# Insert data into two tables from one select in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, ssms, data-migration

I am trying to write a database script to insert the data from a select. 
but now there is an edit in database and I need to insert the same data but in two tables instead of one with foreign key.

Tables:

- `Membership`: Id, Role, AccountName,...
- `MembershipMapper`: Id, MembershipId, Role

I wrote this script:

```
INSERT INTO [server1].[dbo].[Memberships] ([Role], [AccountName] .....)
    SELECT 
        [Role],
        [AccountName],
        ......
    FROM 
        [server2].[dbo].[Memberships]
```

but now the `Role` is in another table. How to insert it? Any ideas?

Comment: At the end you mention the `Role` column is from another table. So do you mean you are inserting data from two tables in one select statement into the `Membership` and `MembershipMapper` table? If so, you will need a join. If not, then you will simply have to insert the data into the tables separately as Sql Server doesn't support multi-table insertion in a single INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this?

INSERT INTO [server1].[dbo].[Memberships] ([Role], [AccountName] .....)

OUTPUT [ID], [Role] INTO MembershipMapper (MembershipId, Role)

```
SELECT 
    [Role],
    [AccountName],
    ......
FROM 
    [server2].[dbo].[Memberships]
```

Comment: did not work because I don't have a Role column in the membership, I only have it in the MembershipMapper

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO [server1].[dbo].[Memberships] ([Role], [AccountName] .....)
    SELECT 
        s.[Role],
        m.[AccountName],
        ......
    FROM 
        [server2].[dbo].[Memberships] m
    INNER JOIN
        [server2].[dbo].[SomeOtherTable] s ON m.ID = s.ID  -- or whatever links the two tables.....
```

Comment: I am afraid that you misunderstand my question, I do not want to insert into one table from two selects, I want to insert into two tables from one select.

Comment: @SamySammour: you **cannot** do that. An insert always goes into **one table** only.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
INSERT INTO [server1].[dbo].[Memberships]
           ([Role]
           ,[AccountName]
           .....)

SELECT memmap.[Role]
      ,mem.[AccountName]
      ......
  FROM [server2].[dbo].[Memberships] AS mem
  JOIN [server2].[dbo].[MembershipMapper] AS memmap
  ON   mem.id = memmap.MembershipId
```

Comment: I am afraid that you misunderstand my question, I do not want to insert into one table from two selects, I want to insert into two tables from one select